# Not getting newly entered data after swiping the layout

Tags: android

I am using swiperefersh layout here and list view and after swaping, I am not getting new data in my list. I have tried lot of times but not able to dot it. please check my below code where i did mistake. My api is calling on Onrefersh method but not able to find newly entered data. I have searched lot of quotes and answers in google but unable to do it. please help me.

```
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener{

    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    private static final String TAG = "ChatActivity";
    String Api_Domain,chatListURL,sendMsgURL;
    private ChatArrayApapter chatArrayAdapter;
    private ListView listView;
    private EditText chatText;
    private ImageView buttonSend;
    ProgressDialog progrss;
    public String group;
    public String groupId;
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar groupName;
    JSONArray jsonArrayChat;
    User user;
    Session session;
    private int pageCount = 1;
    private int entriesPerPage = 20;
    private int totalMsgs;

    public static Activity reference;

    NavigationView navigationView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        reference = this;// do not delete this line




// intialize the views and adapter

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);


        chatArrayAdapter = new ChatArrayApapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.right);
        listView.setAdapter(chatArrayAdapter);

        chatText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msg);
        chatText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    return sendChatMessage1();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

         listView.setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
        listView.setAdapter(chatArrayAdapter);

        //listView.setOnScrollListener(onScrollListener());

        //to scroll the list view to bottom on data change
        chatArrayAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver () {
            @Override
            public void onChanged() {
                super.onChanged();
                listView.setSelection(chatArrayAdapter.getCount() - 1);
            }
        });

        swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

                                        getChatList1();
                                    }
                                }
        );
    }

    // call chat list api

    private void getChatList1(){
        //if ((chatArrayAdapter.getCount() < totalMsgs && listView.getFirstVisiblePosition()== 0)|| (pageCount==1)) {

            RequestQueue mrequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue (ChatActivity.this);
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest (Request.Method.POST, chatListURL, new Response.Listener <String> ( ) {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String res) {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                    try {
                        JSONObject response = new JSONObject (res);
                        jsonArrayChat = response.getJSONArray("groupchatlist");
                        if(jsonArrayChat.length()>0){
                            pageCount++;
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayChat.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject chatObj = (JSONObject) jsonArrayChat.get(i);
                            if (chatObj.getString("user_emailid").equals(user.email)) {
                                chatArrayAdapter.add(true,new ChatMessage(false, chatObj.getString("message"), chatObj.getString("username")));
                            } else {
                                chatArrayAdapter.add(true,new ChatMessage(true, chatObj.getString("message"), chatObj.getString("username")));
                            }
                        }
                        try {
                            JSONArray count = response.getJSONArray("totalcount");
                            JSONObject cnt = (JSONObject) count.get(0);
                            totalMsgs = cnt.getInt("count(id)");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            totalMsgs = 500;
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace ( );
                    }


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener ( ) {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.i ("Tag", "Response: " + error.toString ( ));
                }
            }

            ) {

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map <String, String> params = new HashMap<> ( );
                    //params.put("group", "grp-1");
                    params.put ("group", groupId);
                    params.put("pageNo", String.valueOf(pageCount));
                    params.put("entriesPerPage", String.valueOf(entriesPerPage));
                    return params;
                }
            };

            mrequestQueue.add (stringRequest);
        /*}else{
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }*/
    }


// refresh method
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {

        getChatList1();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must call `chatArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after add all your object into it :

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayChat.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject chatObj = (JSONObject) jsonArrayChat.get(i);
    if (chatObj.getString("user_emailid").equals(user.email)) {
        chatArrayAdapter.add(true,new ChatMessage(false, chatObj.getString("message"), chatObj.getString("username")));
    } else {
        chatArrayAdapter.add(true,new ChatMessage(true, chatObj.getString("message"), chatObj.getString("username")));
    }
}
chatArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() // <-- add this
```

Comment: i am not gerring newly entered data after adding chatArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Are you sure that you getting data from your request (jsonArrayChat.length() > 0) ?
What do you do in your "chatArrayAdapter.add()" method ?

Comment: No bro,  I am getting data from my request (jsonArrayChat.length() > 0) because after swiping the layout it is going on page 2 but my data in page 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this code after adding data into adapter ..

```
        adpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some response time that Server takes to send you the response.So I'd suggest you to add wait for few milliseconds before hitting again in you Runnable.

Comment: You can use Handler.postDelayed() for that.It will help you.